# Capture do function results inside cmd2

Tags: python, cmd2

Here is a simple script using the Python `cmd2` library.

```
import cmd2

class App(cmd2.Cmd):

  result = 0

  # Long computation
  def do_add3(self, arg):
    r = 3 + int(arg)
    print(r)
    self.result = r

  # Scripting
  def do_test(self, arg):
      self.do_add3("4")
      self.do_add3("2")
      self.do_add3("1")
      print(self.result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = App()
  app.cmdloop()
```

[Gist link](https://gist.github.com/circuit4u/96ea6bffb75c5aa3f901c0030c095d3f)

The result of a `do_add3` function is saved (returned) into `self.result`. Later that `do_add3` was called internally with `self.do_add3("4")`.

Is there a better way to return results from a `do_` function, such that I can code like in the following?

```
self.do_add("4") + self.do_add("3") + self.do_add("2")
```

P.S. For example, I can't use `return` inside `do_` function to return value. Is there a better way?

Comment: Please put all things needed to answer your question _inside_ it - that means: do not link to outside resources and dont post code /exceptions as pictures.

Comment: If you don't want to return inside you `do_` function then append the result to some global list inside your `do_` function and later after calling all the `do_` functions add the elements in the shared list?

Comment: I'd like to be able to `return` inside `do_` function, but any `return` call would jump out of `cmd2`. So I am looking for a better way to return value from a `do_` function.